# (Conditional) Expectation of random variable dependent on martingales

Tags: probability, expectation, martingales, conditional-expectation

cannot find intuition to solve problem.

Let $F_n = \sum_{j=1}^{n} X_j   , j \geq 1$  where $X_j = 1$ if a coin toss is heads and $X_j=-1$ if a coin toss is tails.

I first wanted to show it was a martingale, and I did so by showing $F_n = E_n[F_{n+1}] = 0$.

The next part is where it gets a bit tricky. I am asked to show that for:
$L_n = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} F_j (F_{j+1} - F_j) = \frac{F_j^2 - n}{2} $,    for $    n \geq 1$

I understand the logic. $L_n$ describes the cumulative sum of $M_j$ multiplied by the difference between $M_j$ and the expectation of $M_{j+1}$. So, in a sense I see 2 cases, and the $\frac{F_j^2 - n}{2}$ is the 'average' of the two.

However, I cannot rearrange  the equation to get the required result. I have tried properties of conditional expectation and martingale, but cannot transform the equation correctly.

Any insight or clues would be much appreciated. Perhaps I am missing some properties of martingales, expectation, or probability. However, my book does not delve far into the matters.

Comment: You understand that the identity $$2\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} F_j (F_{j+1} - F_j) = F_n^2 - n$$ (correcting your typos) is purely algebraic, right? Hence you can forget "properties of conditional expectation and martingale" to prove it.

Comment: And that $F_{j+1}-F_j ~=~ X_{j+1}$, so ...

Comment: My problem is understanding how to write $X_{j+1} * F_{j}$  algebraically.   I understand that $1$ and $-1$ are the two possible values for $X_{j+1}$.  I dont know how to describe that in terms of $n$ tosses. Thank you for fixing the typos and I apologize for the simplicity of my question.

Comment: $X_{j+1} \cdot  F_j$ is just short for the pointwise multiplication $X_{j+1}(\omega) \cdot F_j(\omega)$ for each $\omega \in \Omega$. (Note that for each fixed $\omega \in \Omega$ both $X_{j+1}(\omega)$ and $F_j(\omega)$ are real numbers.... so there is no trouble multiplying them)